# JS add all items into one array using map

Tags: javascript, arrays, maps

I have an object:

```
[
    {
        "id": 10,
        "name": "comedy"
    },
    {
        "id": 12,
        "name": "documentary"
    },
    {
        "id": 11,
        "name": "scifi"
    }
]
```

I need to take only the `id` values and add them into 1 array like so:

`[ 10, 12, 13 ]`

or

`{ 10, 12, 13 }`

I am trying:

```
const getIDs = value.map( ( { id } ) => ( {
  id: id
} ) );
```

But it creates:

```
[
    {
        "id": 10
    },
    {
        "id": 12
    },
    {
        "id": 11
    }
]
```

Comment: _“But it creates […]”_ — You return [`({ id: id })`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer). Why do you expect anything else? `{ 10, 12, 13 }` isn’t a valid literal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the map just return the id values instead of objects

Here is the quick solution

```js
const values = [
    {
        "id": 10,
        "name": "comedy"
    },
    {
        "id": 12,
        "name": "documentary"
    },
    {
        "id": 11,
        "name": "scifi"
    }
]


const getIDs = values.map(({id}) => id);

console.log(getIDs)
```